# match duplicate email entry ( standard format) in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, email

I've the following table, I would like to match the email.
for example if i find **a.b.c@gmail.com** from this table it should match abc@gmail.com

```
+--------+--------+---------+------------------+------------+-------+
| name   | owner  | species | email_id         | birth      | death |
+--------+--------+---------+------------------+------------+-------+
| Fluffy | Harold | cat     | abc@gmail.com    | 1993-02-04 | NULL  |
| Buffy  | Harold | dog     | abcd@gmail.com   | 1989-05-13 | NULL  |
+--------+--------+---------+------------------+------------+-------+
```

Currently I'm allowing emails to store on tables such as *a.bc@gmail.com**
in this case if I find **abc@gmail.com** it should match **a.bc@gmail.com**

**Another possible mail address**

```
a.bc@gmail.com
ab.c@gmail.com
abc+1@gmail.com
abc+[.....]@gmail.com
```

[.....] - means digits

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: use mysql LIKE or regexp

Comment: using REGEXP is  better way, but how to match above requirements.

Comment: so you want to remove the digits and then check the email match or not?

Comment: Regardless of how this could be achieved, if you want to do this to remove duplicate entries for the same person: abcd.ef@gmail.com and ab.cdef@gmail.com could be two different persons

Answer (score 0):

**hope this will gives you an idea**

```
$newUserEmail = "test4@example.com";
    $matchEmail=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_@-]/s', '', $newUserEmail);
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE email_id = '$newUserEmail'");
    echo "num_rows = ".$result->num_rows."\n";
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE email_id = '$matchEmail'");

    echo "matchEmail= ".$result1->num_rows."\n";

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       echo "Duplicate email\n";
       // do something to alert user about non-unique email
    } elseif($result1->matchEmail > 0){
         echo "Duplicate email\n"; // regex match email found 

    }
    else{

      $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO your_table "); // make your insert query here 
      if ($result === false) {echo "SQL error:".$mysqli->error;}
    }
```

Comment: I've updated my question, please see the question again.

Comment: Good idea, But it actually takes some time to finish all process. It will be better if we deal with MySQL

Comment: preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z_@-]/s', '', $newUserEmail); actually it strips all numbers. I allow email with numbers.

Comment: a.bc@gmail.com
ab.c@gmail.com 
these two email id's may associate with different users.. 
why don't use a email confirmation and check for only unique email id's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104251/discussion-between-jaya-jeeth-and-santosh).